# Linq select multiple ID's (Primary Keys) from Integer List

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have an integer list

```
''# VB
Dim ResultIDsas List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)

// C#
List<int> ResultIDs= new List<int>();
```

I add to that list by looping through the results of a Lucene Read.

```
''#VB
While (i <= (page * 10) AndAlso i < HitCollection.Length)
    Dim document As Document = HitCollection.Doc(i)
    Dim _event As New Domain.[Event]

    ResultIDs.Add(document.[Get]("ID"))
    i += 1
End While

// C#
while ((i <= (page * 10) && i < HitCollection.Length)) {
    Document document = HitCollection.Doc(i);
    Domain.Event _event = new Domain.Event();

    ResultIDs.Add(document.Get("ID"));
    i += 1;
}
```

Now here's where the question comes in.

Say my List of Integers is `[1,5,6,19,22]`

What would a linq (lambda) expresion look like when I need to query my service?

```
''# VB
EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (e.ID = 1))

// C#
EventService.QueryEvents().Where((System.Object e) => (e.ID == 1));

// Obviously these will simply grab ID of "1" which is not what we want.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here, but this seems to be what you're after.

```
''# VB.NET
EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (ResultIDs.Contains(e.ID))
```

And in C#:

```
// C#
EventService.QueryEvents().Where((System.Object e) => (ResultIDs.Contains(e.ID)));
```

Comment: awesome thanks. I was trying the other way around cuz my brain doesn't work lambda all that well yet `e.ID.Contains(ResultIDs)` - which obviously didn't work.

Comment: Super-cool.  This is how Linq-to-SQL works too, which is a bit of a transition going from `Field IN (1,2,3)` in SQL to `myList.Contains(Field)` in Linq.  One more thing - .Contains() is an extension off of IEnumerable(), so I don't think you need to rely on your `ResultIDs` collection to be an IList if that isn't convenient.

Answer (score 2):

```
EventService.QueryEvents().Where(e => list.Contains(e.ID));
```

this would generate the equivalent of SELECT ... WHERE e.ID in (1,5,...)

Comment: thanks @Jaime. I gave @mattmc3 the "accept" simply because he answered first. +1 anyways.